Firebase emulator exports failing when exporting mock data to file
I'm working on this web application JavaScript project where I start the project with:
firebase emulators:start --import=./mockserver --export-on-exit

Its able to read the mock database that I have in the directory when it starts.
However, when I close the project, it's supposed to export whatever test data that I have read and written to, but it showed me this fail message:

[!  emulators: Export failed: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'firebase-export-98746848' -> 'mockserver directory']

I'm using windows 11 and vsc
I have tried running VSC with admin privilege and changing all the folders with full control on windows, turning off antivirus, but this issue kept persisting.
I tried following some of these steps but it's still not working.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1112
